# Count full months between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.1, generate-series

I've been working on this for a few hours with no luck and have hit a wall. My data looks like this:

```
Date1          Date2
2012-05-06     2012-05-05
2012-03-20     2012-01-05
```

What I'm trying to do is add 1 to the count for every month between two dates. So my output would ideally look like this:

```
Year    Month    Sum
2012    2        1
```

In other words, it should check for "empty" months between two dates and add 1 to them.

This is the code I've worked out so far. It will basically count the number of months between the two dates and group them into months and years.

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date2::date) as "Year", 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date2::date) as "Month",
    SUM(DATE_PART('year', Date1::date) - DATE_PART('year', Date2::date)) * 12 +
    (DATE_PART('month', Date1::date) - DATE_PART('month', Date2::date))
FROM
    test
GROUP BY 
    "Year", 
    "Month",
ORDER BY
    "Year" DESC, 
    "Month" DESC;
```

This is where I'm stuck - I don't know how to actually add 1 for each of the "empty" months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Test setup

With some sample rows (should be provided in the question):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   test_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , date1   date NOT NULL
 , date2   date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test(date1, date2)
VALUES
   ('2012-03-20', '2012-01-05')  -- 2012-02 lies in between
 , ('2012-01-20', '2012-03-05')  -- 2012-02 (reversed)
 , ('2012-05-06', '2012-05-05')  -- nothing
 , ('2012-05-01', '2012-06-30')  -- still nothing
 , ('2012-08-20', '2012-11-05')  -- 2012-09 - 2012-10
 , ('2012-11-20', '2013-03-05')  -- 2012-12 - 2013-02
;
```

#### Postgres **9.3** or newer

Use a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT to_char(mon, 'YYYY') AS year
     , to_char(mon, 'MM')   AS month
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('mon',    least(date1, date2)::timestamp) + interval '1 mon' AS d1
        , date_trunc('mon', greatest(date1, date2)::timestamp) - interval '1 mon' AS d2
   FROM   test
   ) sub1
 , generate_series(d1, d2, interval '1 month') mon  -- implicit CROSS JOIN LATERAL
WHERE  d2 >= d1 -- exclude ranges without gap right away
GROUP  BY mon
ORDER  BY mon;
```

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Postgres 9.2 or older

No `LATERAL`, yet. Use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT to_char(mon, 'YYYY') AS year
     , to_char(mon, 'MM')   AS month
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(d1, d2, interval '1 month') AS mon
   FROM  (
      SELECT date_trunc('mon',    least(date1, date2)::timestamp) + interval '1 mon' AS d1
           , date_trunc('mon', greatest(date1, date2)::timestamp) - interval '1 mon' AS d2
      FROM   test
      ) sub1
   WHERE  d2 >= d1 -- exclude ranges without gap right away
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY mon
ORDER  BY mon;
```

#### Result

```
 year | month | ct
------+-------+----
 2012 |     2 |  2
 2012 |     9 |  1
 2012 |    10 |  1
 2012 |    12 |  1
 2013 |     1 |  1
 2013 |     2 |  1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=663a0fc1eab25650ddf0a035ff9daf97)*
[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7e616/1)

#### Explanation

You are looking for *complete* calendar months between the two dates.

These queries work with any dates or timestamps in ascending or descending order and should perform well.

The `WHERE` clause is optional, since [**`generate_series()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) returns no row if start > end. But it should be a bit faster to exclude empty ranges a priori.

The cast to `timestamp` makes it a bit cleaner and faster. Rationale:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Comment: Thank you that works amazingly! Sorry for not being clear earlier. Is there any way of not having to input all the dates into the query? I have thousands of rows with these dates so ideally I would need the query to read them directly from the table. Thank you again!

Comment: My list of dates is also not in order so I guess that makes it more complicated? I've tried adapting your query so that it can just take two column names as input values but can't get it to work.

Comment: Ah I finally got it to work :) Thanks for your input, much appreciated! Here's what the query looks like: http://pastebin.com/gHpVtPZe

Comment: @Philip: I see you figured it out: just remove the first CTE and replace `x` with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can simply substract/add dates in postgresql

```
'2001-06-27 14:43:21'::DATETIME - '2001-06-27 14:33:21'::DATETIME = '00:10:00'::INTERVAL
```

So in your case that request part should look like

```
DATE_PART('month', Date1::datetime - Date2::datetime) as "MonthInterval"
```

Comment: Sure, I tried that but I have dates in several years so subtracting a date in December from a date in January will return a negative number. My main problem here is adding a number to each "emtpy" month :)

Comment: @Philip: I honestly do not understand what you are trying to achieve. If you cast the date values to timestamp, you will get the difference in days; if the left date is earlier then the right date, result is always positive.

Comment: Sorry about that Martin, it made sense when I wrote it. Erwin (above) understood what I meant after some initial trouble it seems. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

age(timestamp1, timestamp2) => returns interval

the we try to extract year and month out of the interval and add them accordingly.

> select extract(year from age(timestamp1, timestamp2))*12 + extract(month from
>   age(timestamp1, timestamp2))