# What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, lateral-join

Since PostgreSQL came out with the ability to do `LATERAL` joins, I've been reading up on it since I currently do complex data dumps for my team with lots of inefficient subqueries that make the overall query take four minutes or more.

I understand that `LATERAL` joins may be able to help me, but even after reading articles like [this one](http://blog.heapanalytics.com/postgresqls-powerful-new-join-type-lateral/) from Heap Analytics, I still don't quite follow.

What is the use case for a `LATERAL` join? What is the difference between a `LATERAL` join and a subquery?

Comment: http://blog.heapanalytics.com/postgresqls-powerful-new-join-type-lateral/  and http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/ (SQL Server's `apply` is the same as the `lateral` from the SQL standard)

Comment: The `LATERAL` keyword belongs to its following _derived table_ (subquery), i.e. **it's not a JOIN type**.

Answer (score 361, accepted):

#### What *is* a `LATERAL` join?

The feature was introduced with PostgreSQL 9.3. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

> Subqueries appearing in `FROM` can be preceded by the key word
> `LATERAL`. This allows them to reference columns provided by preceding
> `FROM` items. (Without `LATERAL`, each subquery is evaluated
> independently and so cannot cross-reference any other `FROM` item.)
>
> Table functions appearing in `FROM` can also be preceded by the key
> word `LATERAL`, but for functions the key word is optional; the
> function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by
> preceding `FROM` items in any case.

Basic code examples are given there.

#### More like a *correlated* subquery

A `LATERAL` join is more like a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), not a plain subquery, in that expressions to the right of a `LATERAL` join are evaluated once for each row left of it - just like a *correlated* subquery - while a plain subquery (table expression) is evaluated *once* only. (The query planner has ways to optimize performance for either, though.)
Related answer with code examples for both side by side, solving the same problem:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

For returning *more than one column*, a `LATERAL` join is typically simpler, cleaner and faster.
Also, remember that the equivalent of a correlated subquery is **`LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`**:

- [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)

#### Things a subquery can't do

There *are* things that a `LATERAL` join can do, but a (correlated) subquery cannot (easily). A correlated subquery can only return a single value, not multiple columns and not multiple rows - with the exception of bare function calls (which multiply result rows if they return multiple rows). But even certain set‑returning functions are only allowed in the `FROM` clause. Like `unnest()` with multiple parameters in Postgres 9.4 or later. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

> This is only allowed in the `FROM` clause;

So this works, but cannot (easily) be replaced with a subquery:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (a1 int[], a2 int[]);
SELECT * FROM tbl, unnest(a1, a2) u(elem1, elem2);  -- implicit LATERAL
```

The comma (`,`) in the `FROM` clause is short notation for `CROSS JOIN`.
`LATERAL` is assumed automatically for table functions.
About the special case of `UNNEST( array_expression [, ... ] )`:

- [How do you declare a set-returning-function to only be allowed in the FROM clause?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160310/3684)

#### Set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list

You can also use set-returning functions like `unnest()` in the `SELECT` list directly. This used to exhibit surprising behavior with more than one such function in the same `SELECT` list up to Postgres 9.6. [But it has finally been sanitized with Postgres 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) and is a valid alternative now (even if not standard SQL). See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Building on above example:

```
SELECT *, unnest(a1) AS elem1, unnest(a2) AS elem2
FROM   tbl;
```

Comparison:

[fiddle for pg 9.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/asUCZoT5)
[fiddle for pg 10](https://dbfiddle.uk/C42oryLC)

**To note:** a (combination of) set-returning function(s) in the `SELECT` list that produces **no rows** eliminates the row. Internally it translates to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL ROWS FROM ...`, not to `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`!

[fiddle for pg 16](https://dbfiddle.uk/AeiIKq95) demonstrating the difference.

#### Clarify misinformation

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> For the `INNER` and `OUTER` join types, a join condition must be
> specified, namely exactly one of `NATURAL`, `ON` ***join_condition***,
> or `USING` (***join_column*** [, ...]). See below for the meaning.
> For `CROSS JOIN`, none of these clauses can appear.

So these two queries are valid (even if not particularly useful):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.t_id = t.t_id) t ON true;

SELECT *
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.t_id = t.t_id) t;
```

While this one is not:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.t_id = t.t_id) t;
```

That's why [Andomar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28551339/939860) code example is correct (the `CROSS JOIN` does not require a join condition) and [Attila's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28550962/939860) <strike>is</strike> was not.

Comment: Cleaner and faster?
Like magnitudes faster in some cases. I had a query that went from days to seconds after switching to LATERAL.

Answer (score 138):

The difference between a non-`lateral` and a `lateral` join lies in whether you can look to the left hand table's row.  For example:

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
cross join lateral
        (
        select  *
        from    t2
        where   t1.col1 = t2.col1 -- Only allowed because of lateral
        ) sub
```

This "outward looking" means that the subquery has to be evaluated more than once.  After all, `t1.col1` can assume many values.

By contrast, the subquery after a non-`lateral` join can be evaluated once:

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
cross join
        (
        select  *
        from    t2
        where   t2.col1 = 42 -- No reference to outer query
        ) sub
```

As is required without `lateral`, the inner query does not depend in any way on the outer query.  A `lateral` query is an example of a `correlated` query, because of its relation with rows outside the query itself.

Comment: how does `select * from table1 left join t2 using (col1)` compare? It's unclear to me when a join using / on condition is insufficient and it would make more sense to use lateral.

Answer (score 50):

### Database table

Having the following `blog` database table storing the blogs hosted by our platform:

[image: Blog table]

And, we have two blogs currently hosted:

| id | created_on | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-09-30 | Vlad Mihalcea's Blog | https://vladmihalcea.com |
| 2 | 2017-01-22 | Hypersistence | https://hypersistence.io |

### Getting our report without using the SQL LATERAL JOIN

We need to build a report that extracts the following data from the `blog` table:

- the blog id
- the blog age, in years
- the date for the next blog anniversary
- the number of days remaining until the next anniversary.

If you're using PostgreSQL, then you have to execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
  b.id as blog_id,
  extract(
    YEAR FROM age(now(), b.created_on)
  ) AS age_in_years,
  date(
    created_on + (
      extract(YEAR FROM age(now(), b.created_on)) + 1
    ) * interval '1 year'
  ) AS next_anniversary,
  date(
    created_on + (
      extract(YEAR FROM age(now(), b.created_on)) + 1
    ) * interval '1 year'
  ) - date(now()) AS days_to_next_anniversary
FROM blog b
ORDER BY blog_id
```

As you can see, the `age_in_years` has to be defined three times because you need it when calculating the `next_anniversary` and `days_to_next_anniversary` values.

And, that's exactly where LATERAL JOIN can help us.

### Getting the report using the SQL LATERAL JOIN

The following relational database systems support the `LATERAL JOIN` syntax:

- Oracle since 12c
- PostgreSQL since 9.3
- MySQL since 8.0.14

SQL Server can emulate the `LATERAL JOIN` using `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`.

LATERAL JOIN allows us to reuse the `age_in_years` value and just pass it further when calculating the `next_anniversary` and `days_to_next_anniversary` values.

The previous query can be rewritten to use the LATERAL JOIN, as follows:

```
SELECT
  b.id as blog_id,
  age_in_years,
  date(
    created_on + (age_in_years + 1) * interval '1 year'
  ) AS next_anniversary,
  date(
    created_on + (age_in_years + 1) * interval '1 year'
  ) - date(now()) AS days_to_next_anniversary
FROM blog b
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT
    cast(
      extract(YEAR FROM age(now(), b.created_on)) AS int
    ) AS age_in_years
) AS t
ORDER BY blog_id
```

And, the `age_in_years` value can be calculated one and reused for the `next_anniversary` and `days_to_next_anniversary` computations:

| blog_id | age_in_years | next_anniversary | days_to_next_anniversary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 2021-09-30 | 295 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-01-22 | 44 |

Much better, right?

The `age_in_years` is calculated for every record of the `blog` table. So, it works like a correlated subquery, but the subquery records are joined with the primary table and, for this reason, we can reference the columns produced by the subquery.

Comment: Cool example. but how does this explain the use of LATERAL?

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the "The age_in_years is calculated for every record of the blog table. So, it works like a correlated subquery, but the subquery records are joined with the primary table, and for this reason, we can reference the columns produced by the subquery" part that was emphasizing the use of LATERAL JOIN.

Comment: Ah yes, I researched a bit more and I think I understand now. A CROSS JOIN can't be used because you can't use correlation (ie referencing the source table), that's what the LATERAL keyword then does.

Answer (score 25):

One thing no one has pointed out is that you can use `LATERAL` queries to apply a user-defined function on every selected row.

For instance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_company(companyId varchar(255))
RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM company_settings WHERE "company_id"=company_id;
        DELETE FROM users WHERE "company_id"=companyId;
        DELETE FROM companies WHERE id=companyId;
    END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, name, created_at FROM companies WHERE created_at < '2018-01-01'
) c, LATERAL delete_company(c.id);
```

That's the only way I know how to do this sort of thing in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 22):

First, [Lateral and Cross Apply is same thing](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/12/18/add-lateral-joins-or-cross-apply-to-your-sql-tool-chain/). Therefore you may also read about Cross Apply. Since it was implemented in SQL Server for ages, you will find more information about it then Lateral.

Second, **according to my understanding**, there is nothing you can not do using subquery instead of using lateral. But:

Consider following query.

```
Select A.*
, (Select B.Column1 from B where B.Fk1 = A.PK and Limit 1)
, (Select B.Column2 from B where B.Fk1 = A.PK and Limit 1)
FROM A
```

You can use lateral in this condition.

```
Select A.*
, x.Column1
, x.Column2
FROM A LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  Select B.Column1,B.Column2,B.Fk1 from B  Limit 1
) x ON X.Fk1 = A.PK
```

In this query you can not use normal join, due to limit clause. 
Lateral or Cross Apply can be used [when there is not simple join condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join).

There are more usages for lateral or cross apply but this is most common one I found.

Comment: Exactly, I wonder why PostgreSQL uses `lateral` instead of `apply`. Perhaps Microsoft patented the syntax?

Comment: @Andomar AFAIK `lateral` is in the SQL standard but `apply` isn't.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` requires a join condition. Make it `ON TRUE` unless you want to restrict somehow.

Comment: Erwin is right, you'll get an error unless you use a `cross join` or an `on` condition

Comment: @Andomar: Spurred by this misinformation I added another answer to clarify.

Comment: The updated query is incorrect again. You cannot join on `X.Fk1` because it's not in the result of the subquery. If you include `Fk1` in the subquery it will be formally correct but still exhibit exotic behavior. It selects an arbitrary row from `B` and only joins it to `A` if  `Fk1` happens to match `A.PK`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Could you check it again?

Comment: `and Limit 1`?  Is that a typo or a valid construct with which I am not familiar?

Comment: "there is nothing you can not do using subquery instead of using lateral" --> consider rephrasing the conditional negatives - not easy (for me) to understand